# Why rtf code doesn't output in readable format when opened in word doc

Tags: php, rtf

I already have an rtf string pulled from a mysql column. 
[image]

Then, i did some string replacement, and then output this same rtf string for download/opened by word. But it still shows the rtf code.
It should already be human readable after opening it in word right?

This is the document content after clicking view/download.
[image]

But, before above view, I got this error: (not sure if this is rtf related)
[image]

This is my code snippet for the outputting the rtf doc.

```
$title = $_GET["rtf"];    
$attachornot="attachment";
header("Content-Type: text/rtf"); 
header('Content-Disposition: '.$attachornot.'; filename="'.$title.'"');
echo $rtf_content;
```

Do you guys know what I did wrong here? 
Thanks!

Comment: Do you you know what went wrong?... :(

Comment: Try with `application/rtf` instead of `text/rtf`

Comment: i tried. doesn't work. hmmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `ob_end_clean();` before calling `header()` fixed this :)

thanks to my friend.

Comment: Be sure to make this as the answer.